# How Would it Affect the Galactic Economy if One Planet Controlled 99%+ of the Galaxy's Gold and Silver?

Tags: planets, economy, geology, currency, galactic

The Planet Aurea has by far the most gold and silver out of any planet of the entire galaxy (thanks to two mountain ranges it has, one around the size of the US portion of the Rocky Mountains made almost completely of gold ore, and the other around the size of the Atlas Mountains made almost completely of silver ore), and its exports amount to <99% of the galactic total. How dependent would the galactic economy be on this one planet if this is where all the precious metals used in minting coins was coming from?

Comment: Why would they mint coins out of gold and silver instead of something that can be sourced locally? You can make coins out of dozens of metals, countless types of stone, wood, paper... you name it, somebody's probably tried to make a coin out of it.

Comment: One remark about these coins.. maybe you could change it.. because the answer would rather depend on economic (production) use of gold and silver, like in parts and electronics. Monetary use of gold and silver, for coins, is already abolished now, it will be ancient at the time of this civilization. There will imho never be a intergalactic civilization with a common economy, depending on silver and gold for *coins*.

Comment: To answer this we'd need to know what sort of galactic economy exists in your world. To the best of our knowledge currently one planet (Earth) currently controls 100% the galactic total of extracted gold and silver.

Comment: How does a resource like coins of conspicuous value get used-up? It strikes me that once they're in circulation they get worn-down over decades but mainly reclaimed when they're dented or otherwise defaced - where they're recycled and re-minted with minimal losses. So, what I'm saying is, apart from slight losses over a long time I'm not sure that I see the issue - unless the economies are on the [Gold Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_standard) or equivalent.

Comment: "and its exports amount to <99% of the galactic total." It literally can't do that, not unless everybody else literally refuses to mine any gold and silver. Galaxy is not a backyard, it has hundreds of billions of star systems, *EACH* probably containing about as much mineable gold as this Aurea planet does, in form of rare earth asteroids and ore deposits on planets.

Comment: On these interstellar scales of galaxy-wide communities, gold would be just another resource with relatively limited use, and the value of money would be derived from something else completely - computational power, for examle.

Comment: *"Precious metals used in minting coins":* what? Why would a galaxy-spanning civilization use physical money, and specifically physical money represented by coins with intrinsic value? We have just begun exploring *one* star system and we have long ago abandoned such primitive ideas. As far as I know there not even one single country in the world using coins with intrinsic value. You may try to find out why such coins went out of fashion about 100 years ago.

Comment: @AlexP: Don't be too sure those coins went out of fashion :-)  They're readily available, though not much used in trade because the value IS intrinsic.  But value depends on supply & demand: if Aurea has a lot of gold, it won't be worth much locally. Other planets probably won't want it except for industrial & decorative uses, and probably have enough at home to supply their needs.

Comment: Any star system with a decent amount of metals in will have plenty of gold. See also, [16 Psyche](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/44313/does-the-asteroid-16-psyche-contain-this-much-gold) in our own asteroid belt, which might contain as much as 20 **teratonnes** of gold. In one asteroid.

Comment: Gold is very common in the universe, so there would be no basis for a monopoly like you suggest (https://www.livescience.com/where-did-gold-come-from.html). Besides, it would likely be far cheaper to synthesize gold in a reactor than to ship it across interstellar distances. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthesis_of_precious_metals#Gold)

Answer (score 4):

Well, first of all, nobody (except possibly the inhabitants of this particular planet) would use gold or silver for coinage, or more generally as a common medium of exchange or store of value.  Why would they, when 1) they barely have any, and 2) they know someone else has lots?  If they *did* formerly use gold and silver as forms of high-value currency due to their rarity, they'd surely be forced to stop doing that as soon as this Planet Aurea was discovered and the price of gold and silver instantly crashed.

(Possible exception: if there was powerful government that immediately conquered Aurea, or at least managed to impose strict controls on the export of gold and silver from it, they *might* be able to prevent the crash and artificially preserve the scarcity of those metals in the rest of the galaxy.  But that's an unstable situation that's unlikely to last very long, and it's likely that any gold or silver coinage will suffer relatively rapid inflation as metals from Aurea will gradually trickle out to the rest of the galaxy, whether due to smuggling or simply due to the government using them as a source of funding for itself.)

---

Anyway, given that gold or silver is pretty unlikely to be used as a medium of exchange in your scenario, the rest depends on just how much intrinsic value those metals retain.  In the real world as we know it, both gold and silver have some niche applications in electronics and other industries due to their high thermal and electrical conductivity and (especially for gold) resistance to corrosion, but adequate substitutes for most of those uses exist, or could be developed if necessary.  So it seems unlikely that Aurea will end up dominating the galactic economy simply due to having a near-monopoly on an essential resource.

Of course, if e.g. starship engines in your setting just *had to* be made of gold, and nothing else would suffice (or be nearly as efficient or practical), then this could change.  In that case, to be honest, we'd most likely end up back in the scenario where the biggest galactic power invades Aurea, or at least uses their diplomatic and military strength to gain access to the planet's resources (compare e.g. [petroleum politics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petroleum_politics) in the real world), at least unless Aurea itself manages to diplomatically maneuver to retain its independence (which would likely involve either a very close relationship with a single major power, to the point of becoming independent in name only, or a precarious balancing act of granting multiple foreign powers access to their resources in exchange for guarantees of independence).

Comment: Re the price of gold & silver crashing, you might consider what happened to the Spanish economy as a consequence of the large amounts of gold & silver brought back from the New World.